# Accessing ActiveX object from Workbook_Open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with several buttons. When the button is pressed the background changes colour, so I have used an ActiveX Button.

I need to reset all the background colours when the workbook is opened but I can't figure out how to, or even if it possible to, access the ActiveX control from `Workbook_Open` event handler, or some other module.

So, that's the question:

- How can I access ActiveX Control properties from `Workbook_Open`?
- Or, How can I reset multiple ActiveX Control backgrounds when the workbook opens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through them and set the color

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, objBtn As OLEObject
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    For Each objBtn In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(objBtn.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
            objBtn.Object.BackColor = &H8000000F
        End If
    Next objBtn

End Sub
```

> This must be placed in your workbook's module.